# Isolating potassium chloride from sodium chloride and potassium hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, precipitation, salt

Assume that you have an aqueous solution of sodium chloride and potassium hydroxide. Is it possible to isolate potassium chloride from this?

$$\ce{Na+(aq) + Cl-(aq) + K+(aq) + OH-(aq) -> Na+(aq) + OH-(aq) + KCl(s)}$$

Since all involved salts/salt combinations are highly water-soluble, I'm not sure how one could isolate the potassium chloride. Is there maybe a way to selectively precipitate the sodium via a non-water soluble salt?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135437/discussion-on-question-by-sarahslvmn-isolating-potassium-chloride-from-sodium-ch).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to buy $\ce{KCl}$, or to prepare it by neutralization of $\ce{KOH}$ and $\ce{HCl}$.

If it happens you have mixed solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{KOH}$, neutralize it first by $\ce{HCl}$ (pH meter or pH indicator paper strips).

From [Wikipedia solubility table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table) one can conclude that while $\ce{NaCl}$ solubility almost does not depend on temperature, solubility of $\ce{KCl}$ is almost twice at 100 °C, compared 0 °C.

My suggestion is fractional crystallization:

1. Partially evaporate the solution until significant mass of salts crystallizes.
2. Heat the mixture to near boiling and mix well - part of $\ce{KCl}$ would dissolve.
3. Separate the precipitate enriched by $\ce{NaCl}$.
4. Cool down solution and let crystalyze salt enriched by $\ce{KCl}$.
5. With both precipitates and residual solution, you can recursively repeat the procedure.
6. You can set a system of N batches, where $\ce{NaCl}$ enriched precipitate would go to direction of the batch more enriched by $\ce{NaCl}$ and vice versa.
7. If it looks complicated to you, buy $\ce{KCl}$ or remember the Pierre and Marie Curie  struggles with the isolation of traces of $\ce{RaCl2}$ from $\ce{BaCl2}$, where their solubilities are much closer.

Another option is using about 3 times better solubility of $\ce{NaCl}$ in methanol, compared to $\ce{KCl}$. But as it is like $\pu{5 g/L}\ \ce{KCl}$ and $\pu{15 g/L}\ \ce{NaCl}$, there would be extensive solvent manipulation with price and safety issues.

As useful info, here is the question/answer about the [solubility diagram of mixtures of both salts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143848/how-to-read-mutual-solubility-curves-of-salts-with-a-common-ion)

Comment: The solubility of a salt like $\ce{NaCl}$ or $\ce{KCl}$ is not the same in pure water and in a solution of another salt.  Please look at solubility diagrams $\ce{NaCl - KCl}$ !

Comment: @Maurice I am well aware of it. :-) In fact, I have [answered](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/143859/35806) some question with such a diagram last year. The solubility in pure water is just a guidance, there is not totally messed up relation of their temperature dependencies.(seen at the diagram as well).

Comment: Ion exchange chromatography *could* be an option, too. A couple of (late) transition metals are separated from each other this way; the value attributed to them justifies the investment.  It very well may be a different story for NaCl, in economic perspective.

Answer (score 1):

[NaCl](http://periodic-table-of-elements.org/SOLUBILITY/sodium_chloride) is about three times as soluble as [KCl](http://periodic-table-of-elements.org/SOLUBILITY/potassium_chloride) in methanol at room temp. That said, while it *might barely* be feasible to separate their salt that way, assuming nearly 100% solvent recovery, and near-zero energy cost (perhaps waste geothermal?), the most efficient commercial method to separate various salts is with [evaporation ponds](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2005.1334.1339).

That said, this is *not* an answer for your question on separating a few liters of solution, but I've written it as one to add the links. If others think this should be placed as a comment, I'll try to do so.

Comment: I was thinking about methanol too, in the deleted comment, but decided against it.